# why i am not able to read Html Content from a website in a file?

Tags: java, url

I have made a java program where in i can use any website to read its Html Content using Scanner class and Varargs.I am not able to get the output while i am using Scanner class and VarArgs.

Below is the following Code.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadWebsite 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {

    URL oracle = new URL(args[0]); 
    Scanner s=new Scanner(oracle.openStream()); 

    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
    }
  s.close();
 }
}

OutputShown
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at oodlesTech.ReadWebsite.main(ReadWebsite.java:15)
```

Comment: how did you run this??

Comment: As @FastSnail has asked, how did you run this? In order for your logic to work you have to supply a list of arguments when the program is executed. Otherwise the args array is empty and trying to access it would result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I didn't knew how to run from eclipse.Thankx Problem Solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running from eclipse you have to pass the arguments.

right click program - > run as - > run configurations -> arguments ->program arguments . in this tab pass the actual url which will be passed as args[0] to your main method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the argument to your java program. 
For your testing you can either hard code it in code e.g. `URL oracle = new URL("http://www.google.com");` or pass an argument to your java program, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756377/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-main-method-dynamically)