# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing args

Tags: java

When I run this code:

```
public class Calc2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result;
        result = Double.parseDouble(args[0]) + Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at Calc2.main(Calc2.java:4)
```

Comment: Post **the error**, not a badly-clipped screenshot of the error.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756377/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-main-method-dynamically

Comment: here is the full image

Comment: It says ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeception.  That's a big clue.  Look at line 4.  You access the args array twice at index 0 and index 1.  Maybe args doesn't hold what you think it does.  Invest your time in learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: You're missing the point: Post the error **as text**, using copy and paste. Images are not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive this error message because the length of the `args` array is shorter that the position you are tring to access. As the other answers have mentioned, you may not be sending the command line arguments, or you may be sending only one, and when you try to access the second one (`args[1]`) you receive Array index out of bounds exception.

The best thing you can do, is check for the length of the array before you access the values, or even iterating inside a `for` instruction until  the length of the array is reached.

Use this instruction to print the values:

```
for(int i=0; i< arr.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print(Double.parseDouble(args[i]));
}
```

And if it does not show anythng is because you are not passing the arguments to the program.

Comment: how to solve it then

Comment: @omarwael I have updated my answer, you can check it

Comment: iam sorry because iam Beginnerso where to but it