# How do I read and accept custom CLI arguments with name/id/title in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I want to read and accept Custom CLI arguments values when I run my Java program as shown below:

```
java BookSales --books=/path/to/books.list 
--sales=/path/to/sales.list --top_selling_books=3 
--top_customers=2 --sales_on_date=2018-02-01
```

Program must accept the following arguments and be able to use the values on the command line, some required and some optional.

```
--books=/path/to/books.list (required)
--sales=/path/to/sales.list (required)
--top_selling_books=<count> (optional) 
--top_customers=<count> (optional)
--sales_on_date=<date> (optional)
```

What I did was as shown below:

```
String books_path = null;
String sales_path = null;
...
...
for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
    if(args[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("--books=") != -1) {
        books_path = args[i].split("=")[1];
    }
    if(args[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("--sales=") != -1) {
        sales_path = args[i].split("=")[1];
    }
    ...
    ...
}
System.out.println(books_path);
System.out.println(sales_path);
```

Is there a better way to do this using only standard java libraries and packages?

Comment: The conditions are incorrect: I could use `java BookSales hello--books--word=/path/to/books.list` and it would still accet it as the --books argument. And of course, the code will throw a runtime exception if I just use --books without =. So you should be stricter in validating the arguments. But if you really don't want to use a library that already does the job for you, then you'll have to reinvent it, yes. You should at least factor that in a method instead of repeating the same code.

Comment: You can find the solution in below link. Hope this help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756377/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-main-method-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has nothing built-in that allows you to parse commandline arguments beyond standard string manipulation. If you don't want to use libraries like Apache Commons CLI, then you will need to write it yourself.

Writing it yourself is not trivial to do, and can be a timesink. I suggest you reconsider, and just use a library for this.

Your code in the question is a good example of why one shouldn't write it themselves: it is very brittle and already has a number of bugs (see comment by JB Nizet) in the small snippet shown.