# What is wrong with this way of using command line arguments in Java?

Tags: java

My program looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.print("Sum is" + a);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to give as command line arguments two integer numbers, then calculate the sum of the two. I read that this is the  way for Java to receive these parameters, but I'm getting an error:

```
Exception in main thread java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException
```

Why is that? Why am I out of bounds for my array `args`?

Comment: How many command line arguments did you give it?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the length of the arguments array you received, as well as the arguments themselves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass command line arguments to main method dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756377/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-main-method-dynamically)

Comment: @Sweeper I'm actually not giving any arguments, because I get this error from the start.

Comment: @MonicaSmith If you're not giving it any arguments, the array will be empty, so accessing even the element with index 0 will be out of bounds, no?

Comment: @MonicaSmith - You are supposed to give the arguments **at the start**.  If you are trying to run this program from within your IDE, you need to adjust the launcher config  properties to specify what the command line arguments should be.

Comment: `args` contains arguments passed to program at start. For example `myprog.exe 1 2`. Tell us how you start your program and we try to help you with passing those arguments.

Comment: Once you get it running, have in mind that `System.out.print("Sum is" + a);` prints no sum rather than the first operand...

Comment: And if you want to give input after running the program then take input using scanner.

Comment: @dbl that post you linked is about JVM arguments, not what we're talking about here.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yet `java -DsysProp1=sp1 -DsysProp2=sp2 test.ArgsTest pro1 pro2 pro3` answers the question. Yet there would be a better duplicate topic anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Your command line needs to be something like

```
java Main 4 7
```

Then, in your code, `args` would contain two elements, namely `4` and `7`.

If your command line is

```
java Main
```

Then `args` contains zero elements and so when you access `args[0]` you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `args` contains no elements so you can't access the first element because it doesn't exist.

Note that it is usually a good idea to first check how many elements `args` contains because, as you have seen, it is quite easy to launch your java program without the required number of arguments.

```java
args.length
```

will return the number of elements in `args`.